# Is Nutch in local mode independent of Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, web-crawler, nutch

I understand that running Nutch in deploy mode is distributed crawling based on Hadoop but I couldn't fully understand what when we run it in local mode. Is Nutch independent of Hadoop in that case? And is the crawling process in local mode not based on MapReduce?

Answer (score 2):

Nutch is based on MapReduce, regardless of how it runs. The Hadoop libs are dependencies of Nutch, in local mode, Nutch puts the Hadoop related libs on the classpath and runs it all in a single JVM. In distributed mode, the 'hadoop' command is called.

See [Nutch script](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/bin/nutch#L310)
PS: if you use Nutch on a single machine, it makes sense to run it in pseudo distributed mode so that you get the MapReduce UI to monitor the crawl + parallelism etc...

Comment: Ok. So in local mode Nutch uses only MapReduce mechanism of Hadoop and not anything else. Am I right?

Comment: 'anything else' -> HDFS? it won't be used by default. Are we talking about Nutch 1.x BTW?

Comment: Yes I am working with 1.12. How to use HDFS in standalone mode?